# SQL query works on PHPMYADMIN but not working on postman

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, rest

i have a PHP REST API and this function:

```
 function fillProfil($request) {
     require_once 'db.php';
     $emp = json_decode($request->getBody());
     $id = $request->getAttribute("id");


    try {
         $sql = "select * FROM users WHERE id= :id";
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam("id", $id);
         $stmt->execute();
        $wines = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
         $db = null;
        if($wines->type=="client"){
            return json_encode($wines);
        }else{
            $sql = "select * FROM `users` JOIN (`professionnel` JOIN `metiers` ON professionnel.metierid=metiers.id) ON users.id=professionnel.userid  WHERE users.id= :id  ";
            $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam("id", $id);
         $stmt->execute();
        $wines = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
         $db = null;
         return json_encode($wines);
        }



    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
    }
}
```

Problem is with `select * FROM users JOIN (professionnel JOIN metiers ON professionnel.metierid=metiers.id) ON users.id=professionnel.userid  WHERE users.id= :id`  when i execute this query on phpmyadmin it works, but when i execute the function on php my admin its not working, i tried to `json_last_error_msg()` and i got `syntax error`

I think problem is from JSON but im not sure and really dont know how to fix this

Comment: Shouldn't it be `bindParam(':id', $id);` Notice the `:id`

Comment: Nope x) it works this way too

Comment: When i echo ($wines->username) wich is a column from users it works, this is strange..

Comment: Try `$wines = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`